# Applying a patch with git

Tags: git, patch

Everytime i try to apply a patch using git i get this error:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe am --3way --signoff "C:/Users/KV/Desktop/11189-City-Conquest.patch"
Applying: 11189Conquest
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...

warning: squelched 481 whitespace errors
warning: 486 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    src/server/game/Scripting/ScriptLoader.cpp
    src/server/scripts/Custom/CMakeLists.txt
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
Failed to merge in the changes.
Done
Patch failed at 0001 11189Conquest
When you have resolved this problem run "git am --resolved".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git am --skip".
To restore the original branch and stop patching run "git am --abort".
```

Please help me

Comment: Do you have uncommitted changes in your tree? What does 'git status' say?

Comment: Did you try reading the error? It tells you exactly why it's unable to apply the patch.

Answer (score 1):

You have local changes in your working directory as indicated by:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    src/server/game/Scripting/ScriptLoader.cpp
    src/server/scripts/Custom/CMakeLists.txt
```

Commit, reset or stash these and then continue.